# Codeigniter: ajax response contain extra html comment

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter, pyrocms

I am getting an "extra html comment" in every Ajax response.

This issue is only appearing on a live site link like www.sampledomain.com. I have deployed the same code on subdomain like www.sampledomain.com/dev and its working fine there, I am getting right Ajax response.

But on LIVE site, there is a extra code which is "im the usage 12.25 im the usage2 2" attached the every response.

The text "im the usage 12.25 im the usage2 2" is wrapped in html comment tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure it'll be some helper or environment dependent files or a separate file in your server root. Go through these two steps.

- Make a search for `im the usage` in the whole
  project. It'll ensure that your code is clean.
- If nothing found, it means theres something wrong in your server root directory. Inspect server files in root directory and `environment dependent` files.